# Get rid of Tencent in the OneSettings registry

Tags: windows, windows-10

I clean the system from `Tencent` and removed everything except `TargetingAttributes` and `TargetingAttributesVerified`.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\OneSettings
```

How to remove `Tencent` from there?

Comment: Can you not just right-click in Regedit and delete the entries?

Comment: Will it harm the system?

Comment: if you are just deleting the tencent entries, then no, it should not harm the system... but if you are paranoid, you could also export the keys, just in case you need to restore them... but again, i fail to see how it would harm the system. it's really not uncommon for the windows registry to get messy / have left over keys from applications.

Comment: But this registry was not created by Tencent, but by the system

Comment: I myself would just delete it.  You sound a bit peckish so as @jrdnjhntsn points out, backup those (worthless) keys.  If you are EXTRA paraniod, you can use [System Restore](https://www.theverge.com/21266665/windows-10-restore-point-how-to-security-pc-software-registry-configuration) to create a restore point first.  If you are EXTRA EXTRA paranoid, you can use the [Windows 7 backup and restore tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-and-restore-your-pc-ac359b36-7015-4694-de9a-c5eac1ce9d9c) (yes, I know you are 10) to create an image first.